# How to run system commands before program start using Ruby GOD gem

Tags: ruby, god

I use GOD to watch the process => `rake resque:scheduler`

Before run  'rake resque:scheduler ' I have to run `rake resque_schedule:setup`

But the following settings are not working.

I use the ps aux to list the process but the scheduler is not working as I expect.

It should generate tasks periodically.

If I type the 2 commands in shell, it works.

I have no ideas

```
God.watch do |w|


  system("rake resque_schedule:setup ") # run the rake to load environment

  w.name = 'resque-scheduler'
  w.interval = 5.seconds
  w.dir = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'..'))
  # w.start = "rake resque_schedule:setup ; rake resque:scheduler "
  w.start = "rake resque:scheduler "
  w.start_grace = 10.seconds
  w.log = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '.','log','resque-scheduler.log'))
  w.keepalive(:memory_max => 150.megabytes,
              :cpu_max => 50.percent)


end
```

Comment: why `system` command ? If you want to load the environment can that be done in  simply way like `rake environment resque:scheduler`

Answer (score 0):

You should call `rake resque_schedule:setup` before `god.start` call.

For example:

```
system("rake resque_schedule:setup")
god.start
```

Comment: Is it still working when call system command before I kill the process ?

Comment: You mean.. You want to kill `resque_schedule:setup` when god process is killed ?

Comment: No. the GOD watches the `rake resque:scheduler`. if I kill the pid of `rake resque:scheduler`. Will the GOD run the  ` system("rake resque_schedule:setup ")` before restart  `rake resque:scheduler`.

Comment: I think that you have to do in `w.start_if` block.

Comment: Can you please try this (Concatenate both commands in one) : `w.start = "rake resque_schedule:setup; rake resque:scheduler"`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41523/discussion-between-amit-thawait-and-poc)